# Addon development: flake8/Python versions vs. Blender Python versions (Win)

Tags: python, add-on

I am working on a Blender addon and want to check the coding style with flake8 (on Windows 10). I plan to target a couple of Blender releases.

Since Blender's embedded Python doesn't include pip, I installed the latest Python 3.10.2 and used pip to install the latest flake8 (22.something) system-wide. I can run it against my source.

The question is: is flake8 reliable/valid if its Python version doesn't match that of Blender? Or is being "new enough" good enough? Can't find any answers to this anywhere.

For example:

- Blender 2.81a -> Python 3.7.4
- Blender 3.0.1 -> Python 3.9.7

Thanks.

Comment: Hello ! Are you planning on submitting your addon to the official addons that are shipped with Blender ?

Comment: Actually, no. That is a very big responsibility. But if I distribute casually to anyone to try it, I would like to measure up to the "official" standards. Maybe that isn't a reasonable goal. (Retired programmer, perfectionist)

Comment: If you want to go the full perfectionist route, Blender has its own style checker in the repository; but the style guide only requires roughly PEP 8 compliance.  As far as coding style, though, PEP 8 hasn't really changed since around 2013 and Blender's guide hasn't really changed since 2.8 introduced the PREFIX_xT_NAME convention for panel/menu/operator classes, so you should be good to go.

Comment: On a whim I downloaded Visual Studio Code and enabled flake8. It looks like a very nice and convenient way to go. I guess I'm going for PEP 8, and some additional things mentioned at blender.org. Is the PREFIX_xT_NAME convention mentioned in the Blender manual? I've seen it before but can't remember where and I was always a bit unclear on it. Thanks.